# rails 7.1 new with bootstrap fails with dart sass error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to update my Rails app to use bootstrap using a more standard install, so I'm trying to figure out how that's done by default in Rails 7.1 but I can't even get rails new to work with bootstrap.

`rails new . --css bootstrap` fails with error:

```
      insert    config/initializers/assets.rb
  Appending Bootstrap JavaScript import to default entry point
      append    app/javascript/application.js
  Add build:css:compile script
         run    npm pkg set scripts.build:css:compile="sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss:./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules" from "."
         run    yarn build:css:compile from "."
yarn run v1.22.19
$ sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss:./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules
/Users/XXX/rails-new-test/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:116832
    if (ua.indexOf("DumpRenderTree") >= 0) return hooks;
```

I am using:

```
ruby 3.2.1 (2023-02-08 revision 31819e82c8) [x86_64-darwin21]
Rails 7.1.1
Node v21.0.0
Yarn 1.22.19
```

Answer (score 3):

There is [an issue with dart when using Node.js v21](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/53810):

> Applications built with dart2js fail in the most recent release of node.js (node.js 21). This was caused by logic we relied on for years to adjust the program to its underlying runtime (browser, node, d8, jsshell).
>
> [...]
>
> This affects a lot of users. This doesn't affect applications deployed to browsers, but affects any binary deployed to node.js. That includes big projects like dart-sass.

It sounds like it will be fixed soon, but until then, a solution is to downgrade to the previous version (20.8.1) of Node.js.

Comment: Amazing! That's solved it. Thanks!